# Insert multiple check box values in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i want to insert multiple selected checkbox values to be inserted in to one column,
when i search for it, i found that append the values with comma and insert into table
Example:

```
   ID      Value
-------------------
    1        Veg
    2        Non-Veg
    3        Chinese
    4        Italian
```

if user selects 1 3 4 then append with comma like 1,3,4 and insert into table.
appending with comma is not the efficient way, Is there any other way ? please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

How about binary numbers
 for example:

0101

meaning

```
checkbox 1 : true
checkbox 2 : false
checkbox 3 : true
checkbox 4 : false
```

in db it would be stored like 5 (decimal value of binary 0101)

only problem would be if you would like to search users with for example checkbox 3 checked.

In that case just add row for every checkbox user checks. When searching for checkboxes you will get multiple rows with checkbox ids. I believe thats actually the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 
table would be like for order_id 33
tableA

```
order_id    item_id
33            1
33            3
33            4
```

you can get value by inner join 
above table and item, value table

```
(select * from tableA inner join tableB on tableA.item_id=tableB.item_id)
```

tableB

```
item_id      value
 1            Veg
 2            Non-Veg
 3            Chinese
 4            Italian
```

try this

```
$order_id=33;
$ids=$_GET['ids']; // $ids= 1,3,4
$ids_Split= explode(",", $ids);
$cnt=count($ids_Split);
for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
{
mysql_query("insert into hotel_table(order_id,item_id) 
values ($id, $ids_Split[$i])");
}
```

Comment: Naveen i don't think appending with comma and splitting is efficient way

Comment: Your are not inserting the values in table as "1,3,4" we are creating a new entry for each value.

Comment: +1 for describing in details what I have suggested ;) best solution imo

Answer (score 0):

You should never put multiple values in one column which would violate the first narmal form of a database: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Just a column for every boolean field yo need.

Comment: That is another good idea, wouldn't work if number of possible options can increase in the future though...

Comment: Yes, i have 40 checkboxes for now

Answer (score 0):

Creating linked table where you can append multiple rows (1 for each selection) would be the first thing I would think of...